# Как загрузить изображение на сайт с помощью selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Всем привет! У меня проблема с загрузкой файла на сайт restorephotos.io с помощью selenium. Я нашел пример кода для загрузки, но он не работает и выводит ошибку.
Весь код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

chrome = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome.get("https://www.restorephotos.io/restore")
assert "Restore Photos" in chrome.title
fileInput = By.CSS_SELECTOR('input[type=file]')
filePath = r"C:\Users\user\Videos\Little_Women_1\Little_Women_1_000001.jpg"
chrome.find_element(fileInput).send_keys(filePath)
assert "No results found." not in chrome.page_source
```

Часть кода, в котором ошибка: `fileInput = By.CSS_SELECTOR('input[type=file]')`.

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:\LDPlayer\main.py", line 8, in <module>
   fileInput = By.CSS_SELECTOR('input[name=uploader__input-861027]')
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Сайт, по примеру которого я следовал: https://habr.com/ru/post/497922/

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в вашем коде заключается в том, что вы пытаетесь использовать метод `By.CSS_SELECTOR` как функцию.

Интересное у Вас наименование папки с материалами :D Возможное решение для Вас:

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome.get("https://www.restorephotos.io/restore")
assert "Restore Photos" in chrome.title
fileInput = chrome.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type=file]')
filePath = r"C:\Users\user\Videos\Little_Women_1\Little_Women_1_000001.jpg"
fileInput.send_keys(filePath)
assert "No results found." not in chrome.page_source
chrome.quit()
```

Comment: Ваш код работает, но появилась другая проблема: изображение не загружается, постоянная загрузка

Comment: Как понять бесконечная загрузка? 
Загружаемый файл появился в поле для загрузки?

Answer (score 1):

`By.CSS_SELECTOR` - это не функция, а строковая константа.

С селениумом я не работал, но, насколько я могу судить по итогам беглого гугления, проблемную строчку нужно переписать примерно так:

```
fileInput = chrome.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type=file]')
```

А в указанной вами статье примеры определённо не на питоне, я бы не стал на них ориентироваться.

Посмотрите лучше здесь: https://habr.com/ru/post/250975/